# How do I restore a WSS3 Site with just the Content DB?

Tags: sharepoint-server, wss-3.0, content-database

I am dealing with a system crash where I had a WSS3 site in a DMZ with a SQL2005 server remote (inside the Domain). The Web Server and the SQL server both were taken out is a system failure. I was successful in restoring the Web Server but The SQL Server had some issues and had to be rebuilt from scratch. I did have backups of all the DBs on it and was successful in reattaching them. But it caused SID issues with the old SQL User so the SQL account for the SharePoint sites had to be deleted and recreated. My issue was no one knew the old password for the Username for the DB and since the Web Server is NOT a Domain server I know SQL Authentication was used. I spent days trying to find the old SQL Password but came up empty. So I broke down and rebuilt the WSS 3.0 from scratch and got the basic site up and running. I thought I could simply reattach the old ContentDB and be off and running again but no joy. Though the old ContentDB is attached and is being used none of the old content has appeared. (Though I know it is still in that DB). Is this a SiteID issue where the old site and the new site have different IDs? Or am I missing something else. Sorry but SharePoint isn't my strong point so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Couple of questions before give you any solution.

What steps you followed to restore?

- Create a new WSS 3.0 farm and create and configure the web
  applications.
- Configure the AAM settings
- Detach the database which created during the web application
- now restore the old DB and mount it to the web application.

did you follow above steps or something else?

Comment: I created a new farm and configured the new Web Applications. Then I attached the old DBs to the SQL Server. I then added the FBA and initial configuration settings and ensured the new site actually worked. Then I the stsadm addcontentdb command to add the old db to the new site. Should I have deleted the "new" contentdb first? because I didn't. I added the old one back and then deleted the new one that was created during the rebuild process?